# Problema con spinner en android studio

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, spinner

tengo una aplicación la cual carga desde una base de datos hechas con php/mysql una lista de géneros(musicales y cinematográficos) y los carga a un spinner, el problema es que carga mal los elementos, el fondo por defecto es blanco, pero ahora también las letras de los elementos se carga en blanco lo que hace difícil leerlos, por otro lado en el emulador me deja seleccionarlos, pero en el celular cuando instalo el apk no me deja seleccionar ningún elemento.[image: aqui una muestra de como se ve]

---

he probado el segundo método que me pusiste y resulto en esto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución simple cambia el **color** del texto y el **tamaño**:

```
private OnItemSelectedListener OnCatSpinnerCL = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

       ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
       ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(5);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};
```

Otra solución mas "compleja". Crea un archivo `XML` personalizado para tu elemento.

**spinner_item.xml:**

Dale tu color y tamaño personalizados al texto en este archivo.

```
<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#FF0000"         
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

Ahora usa este archivo para mostrar tus artículos como:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
```

No necesita configurar el recurso desplegable. Solo tomará `spinner_item.xml` para mostrar sus artículos en el spinner.